# Question about php and dreamweaver?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I have apache, mysql, php installed manually on windows xp.

How can I make my dreamweaver configurable for php (so it can run php)..

I add this line:

```
<?php print "hello world"; ?>
```

But nothing appears

UPDATE:
I clicked on my site:

Site---->Manage Site-->Edit
Servers---->+ 
Server Folder:D:\Apache2.2\htdocs
Web URL: http://localhost:8080/

Now when I close this and add a new php file,, the php file works..but when I write the code in a regular html file like this:

```
<?php print "hello world"; ?>
```

The address looks like this:
http://localhost:8080/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **This is how on CS5:**

1. Click Site(in toolbar).
2. Click New Site.
3. Select the Servers tab and select the new server cross **+**
4. Select the *Connect using:* option box and choose Local/Network.
5. Select *Server Folder:* as the root to your htdocs.
   e.g:C:\xampp\htdocs and the *Web URL:* as `http://localhost`
6. Click Save.

### Adding a new file to the project:

In the *Business catalyst* panel(to the bottom right), Right click the connection - New file. 
Rename it extension .php and your good to go.

**UPDATE:** PHP will not purse PHP in .html files by default.

Todo this:
Create a *.htaccess* file and place this in it:

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd If you want help, you should write *what* does not work ;)

Comment: the hello world doesnt appear.. but a php file with content appears..<?php
  phpinfo();
--- that does appear when i run on dreamweaver

Comment: Like I said you need to rename it php, unless you specifically set up php to purse .html files it wont... or you could use .htaccess but that's another question

Comment: okay, i got it ,,,all i had to do was to rename the file extention to php..and everything workz

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver does not run PHP itself afaik. You need a Webserver that is able to execute PHP scripts (on Windows I recommend XAMPP apachefriends.org for local testing)

Comment: I installed those programs seperately, i didnt install XAMPP , if i install XAMPP i will have to uninstall the programs that i installed and i want to try to avoid doing so...  i konw that there is a way to run php scripts on dreamweaver as a matter of fact