# Trouble running my PHP files

Tags: php, xampp, dreamweaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about php and dreamweaver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330627/question-about-php-and-dreamweaver)

I am having alot of trouble running my php file. I downloaded XAMPP and have both Apache and MySQL running. Do I need to save the file in a certain place, and what does Dreamweaver mean when it says:

> To preview pages containing server-side code, you need a testing server. Would you like to specify one now?

I have good enough knowledge in HTML and CSS, and have gotten websites running, but I can't seem to get PHP to work. When I just run the code from google chrome plainly it looks like this:

```
"Hello World"
"; phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: The server to specify in Dreamweaver is probably `localhost`.

Comment: First you should read about the basics of PHP http://tut.php-quake.net/en/

Comment: In order for php to work it needs to be put on a server.

Comment: Click the php tag and then visit learn more link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your PHP-files into the `xampp/htdocs` folder, e.g. `xampp/htdocs/hello.php` and then open it in your browser at `http://localhost/hello.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The URL must say `localhost` or whatever you set it to in order to render a PHP page. You also need to make sure PHP handlers are working and correctly parsing PHP files.